# React-native i18next make use yaml files

Tags: react-native, yaml, internationalization, i18next

I can't make i18next use yaml files for translation. Everything works fine with .json, but not with .yml I have no errors just no translation.

My i18n.ts is:

```
import i18n from 'i18next'
import {initReactI18next} from 'react-i18next'

const translation = require('./enyaml.yml')

export const resources = {
  en: {
    translation,
  },
}

i18n.use(initReactI18next).init({
  resources,
  lng: 'en',
  fallbackLng: 'en',
  interpolation: {
    escapeValue: false,
  },
})
```

As I can see this is some trouble with import or support of yaml files. Really appreciate any advices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use yaml files in react-native I installed [babel-plugin-content-transformer](https://github.com/wyattis/babel-plugin-content-transformer)
and add in babel.config.js in plugins

```
['content-transformer', {
  transformers: [{
    file: /\.ya?ml$/,
    format: 'yaml'
  }]
}]
```

Now it works fine and I can use yaml files in my application. But there's new issue application displays .yml file changes only after server restart.

Comment: Hi - do you have a more detailed example of react-native, i18next-react and yaml files working? I've set up `content-transformer` in my babel config but can't seem to read the yaml via my i18next config/init.

Answer (score 0):

I have used i18n for multiple language select.
In assets/lang/en.json,.../hi.json,.../ma.json,.../te.json Based on user selection  u need to pass the json lang txt.

Comment: In case with .json files everything works fine. The question is exactly about yaml files. There is a requirement that tells, that I need to use .yaml instead of .json